# When I want to say "agree with us", can I just say "agree"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wrote an article on whether it’s better to choose friends who always have the same opinions as us or it’s good to have friends who sometimes disagree with us. I hired a freelancer who is a native speaker to improve it. He said my writing was wordy and deleted all my "with us". So, I don't need "with us"? Readers will know I mean "with us"?

> Our lives may be easier with friends who always agree **(with us)**
> because we needn’t waste time arguing.

> Having friends who occasionally disagree **(with us)** can help us grow.

Comment: It could mean 'disagree with one another', so I'd say 'with us' is necessary.